# Unable to create JAXBContext in Java Web service

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I used NetBeans to create a Metro Web service and to be deployed on GlassFish.
I get an error when I try to build but *only* if one of the operations in the web service returns an Object instead of a primitive type or String.

The error:

```
Deploying application in domain failed; Deployment Error -- Exception occured in the wsgen process javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
build-impl.xml:569: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

The containing code:

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=79093) is also a good illustration of your problem:

> The problem is that the custom class has public access for the properties and also it has getter/setter methods.
>   I discover because you can use Netbeans to generate the `WSDL` files for the `Webservice` to inspect them. Doing so it returned the detailed error.
>   If you want to use it, write your Web Service, then go to "`Web Services`" node, select your Web Service, right click it and select "Generate and Copy `WSDL`".

You can find some practical advices here on the [definition of your object](http://www.jseduite.org/doku/cookbook/build-ws#business_object).

And of course you still have the [Java Web Service Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/) exposing the [Requirements of a JAX-WS Endpoint](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html#wp144873).

Answer (score 3):

I found the Solution..

The class I am returning has a public value also, set and get so delete them and worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Above steps didn't work for me.  What did was adding an empty constructor to MyClass of the object being returned, an ArrayList<MyClass>.

(NB6.9.1, GF2.X, Windows XP x64)